# triple record in db when i want to insert

Tags: mysql

I am a student and I have a project for online attendence
I made this code,but  when I tried, it insert 3 records for one roll_number..What I did wrong?

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
include("header.php");
$hostname = "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "attendance_system";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{foreach($_POST['prezenta'] as $id=>$prezenta)
{
    $student_nume=isset($_POST['student_name'][$id]);
    $student_prenume=isset($_POST['roll_name'][$id]);
     $date=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

    mysqli_query($con,"insert into attendence_records(student_name, 
    roll_name, attendence_status, data) SElect 
    student_name,roll_name,'$prezenta','$date' from attendence1");

    //VALUES ('$student_nume','$student_prenume','$prezenta','$date')");


    }
   }

   ?>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel panel-heading">
  <h2>
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="add.php"> Adauga student</a>
  <a class="btn btn-info pull-right" href="viewall.php"> vizualizare</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="well text-center">Data:<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');?> 
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-body">
  <form action="index1.php" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr class="success">
                <th>NR CRT.</th>
                <th>matricola</th>
                <th>nume</th>
                  <th>data</th>
                <th>prezenta</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
 <?php

  $result=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from attendence1");
  $serialnumber=0;
  $counter=0;

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $serialnumber++;
   ?>
   <tr>
             <td><?php echo $serialnumber;?>  </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['roll_name'];?></td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['roll_name'];?> 
      name="roll_name">
            <td><?php echo $row['student_name'];?></td>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['student_name'];?> 
    name="student_name">
            <td><?php echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');?></td>
            <td>
           <input type="radio" name="prezenta[<?php echo $counter;?>]" 
    value="Present  ">Prezent
           <input type="radio" name="prezenta[<?php echo $counter;?>]" 
   value="Absent">Absent
    </td>
        </tr>

 <?php
 $counter++;

  }
   ?>

     </table>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

I tried to put 3 student records as testing

```
1   rwwr    vasile  2017-09-27 22:06:43 Prezent  Absent
2   2233    opm 2017-09-27 22:06:43 Prezent  Absent
3   963 vasile  2017-09-27 22:06:43 Prezent  Absent
```

But in database

```
Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
352
vasile
rwwr
Present  
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
353
opm
2233
Present  
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
354
vasile
963
Present  
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
355
vasile
rwwr
Absent
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
356
opm
2233
Absent
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
357
vasile
963
Absent
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
358
vasile
rwwr
Present  
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
359
opm
2233
Present  
2017-09-27 22:43:30

Modifică Modifică
 Copiază Copiază
 Șterge Șterge
360
vasile
963
Present  
2017-09-27 22:43:30
```

this is the structure of my tables http://prntscr.com/gr95dj -this is the attendence_records and http://prntscr.com/gr95tm this is the attendence1

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Since this is inside a loop are you sure you're creating the correct number of records based on the input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that you will have triple records inserted in your database.

in this line:

```
mysqli_query($con, "insert into attendence_records(student_name, 
roll_name, attendence_status, data)
select student_name, roll_name, '$prezenta', '$date' from attendence1");
```

As for value, you are selecting from your table:

```
select student_name, roll_name, '$prezenta', '$date' from attendence1");
```

This select will return all the current records from this table. So if you have 3 records in your table, then it will return 3 records and then you have a loop for 3 records that you have submitted which will multiply by those 3 records from the table and the result will be these 9 records that you have.

I'm not sure about your login that you are using **`select`** in your **`insert`** statement. Even if you want to do it, I think you should have a **`where clause`** to at least select a certain record to be selected

Comment: sorry I'm a novice at php, so I cannot understand it

Comment: @loana That is not really PHP, but SQL used inside PHP (to access the MySQL database), if you don't have clear how the `insert`, `select` and other database clauses work you should read first  [an SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp)

Comment: @IoanaTimofte OK, if I know your logic then maybe I can help you rewrite your query. After all, I do not think you need a `select` in your query.

Comment: I have 2 tables, one with students and one with attendence and I want to make the attendence for the students that I have. I try to use only insert but in my attendence table it only registered the date and the Absent/present. The name and the roll number has not been registered in the attendence table so I try to use also select.

Comment: Can you please edit you question and add the structure of these two tables to your post?

Comment: @IoanaTimofte OK, your database is not normalize at all. If you have `student_name` and `roll_name` in your `attendence1` table, you **SHOULD** only store the `id` of each of these records in your `attendence_records` table as a `foreign key`. I really recommend you change the design of your database. But if it's out of your hand and you want to keep this design, please let me know to update my answer to meet your needs

Comment: I am not sure I can do like you said, but I try to use something else and now the number of records is normal but is show me like this http://prntscr.com/gra7zf. My db has like 300 students and all I want is to make this in the easiest way possible.

Comment: Easiest way is not always the best way. With this database design, sooner or later you will probably have issues in the near future.

Comment: So should I put foreign key on the roll_name on my attendence1(because is unique) and only insert the roll_name,attendence and date on the attendence_records?